# Grant File Access on Demand

Tags: sharepoint, permissions

Is it possible to grant access to file for a user the moment he tries to access it?

Here's the condition:

1. User1 and User2 works for the same company.
2. User1 uploads a file to a document library that is used by multiple
   different companies.
3. User2 tries to download the file that User1 uploaded.
4. Check if User2 is working for the same company as the user who
   uploaded the file.
5. If yes, grant access.

The reason why I want to do this is because the document library is being used by different companies. The requirement is only users under the same company can access a file uploaded by that company.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You have to arrange the files in the Shared document library in different folders/Document sets.Create SharePoint groups for each company and assign folder level permission, such that users of each company will have permission to respective folders.This way user1 will upload document to his company folder and user 2 since belonging to same company will have access to it.

Alternatively you can also write event handler and make item level permission if you do not want to go for folder level permission.(NOT RECOMMENDED)

Answer (score 0):

You can use folders to achieve this by creating a folder for each company and assigning permissions for user 1 and user 2 to their company folders.
OR
Create a column called company. Users that upload a file to the group can select what company this file belongs to. Based on that column, you can grant the permission to the correct company group. This can be done using workflow, event receiver or an app solution like this: http://truapps.portalfront.com/tru-permission-automation-for-sharepoint.html

Comment: I already know that concept. Unfortunately, that's not feasible at the moment.